# SQL date conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008 here. I am still having issues with converting the dreaded date from the format `INT` to something usable. It works fine when I just convert one column but if I try both the required date and the ship date it gives me the

> conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

error.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    SPSYS07.loc_code, SPSYS07.so_no, SPSYS07.cust_no,    
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), SPSYS07.req_d_date), 101),
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), SPSYS07.ship_date), 101)
FROM 
    SCOT_IQ.dbo.SPSYS07 SPSYS07
WHERE 
    (SPSYS07.loc_code = '103') AND (SPSYS07.order_date = 20120531)
ORDER BY 
    SPSYS07.so_no
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Some data and expected output would be useful.

Comment: You are comparing the `order_date` column against a number, so is that column actually numeric? Are the req_d_date` and `ship_date` numeric as well and use the same format as `order_date`?

Comment: it sounds like some of your integer dates are not stored properly in the table.  Try looking for invalid values.

Comment: You can use something like this to track down the culprit, select * from MyTable where ISDATE(convert(char(8),MyDateColumn))=0

Comment: yes there are some values with only 1 zero in ship_date...

Answer (score 0):

> You can use something like this to track down the culprit, select * from MyTable where > ISDATE(convert(char(8),MyDateColumn))=0 yes
>
> ans: there are some values with only 1 zero in ship_date...

This means you will have to either exclude those rows from your query, use a case expression to give bad values a arbitrary value, or fix the data.  Also, I am pretty sure you will agree, but I will say it anyway... You should be storing date values in a date/datetime data type.  This prevents issues like this and makes things much easier down the road.

Also, Instead of storing a value of 0 in the date column, you should store a value of NULL, or have some arbitrary default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for valid dates in the select, and return NULL if the date is invalid.  Best would be to store the dates in the table as type DATE though.

```
SELECT 
    SPSYS07.loc_code, SPSYS07.so_no, SPSYS07.cust_no,    
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(CONVERT(CHAR(8), SPSYS07.req_d_date)) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), SPSYS07.req_d_date), 101) END AS 'req_d_date',
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(CONVERT(CHAR(8), SPSYS07.ship_date)) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), SPSYS07.ship_date), 101) END AS 'ship_date'
FROM 
    SCOT_IQ.dbo.SPSYS07 SPSYS07
WHERE 
    (SPSYS07.loc_code = '103') AND (SPSYS07.order_date = 20120531)
ORDER BY 
    SPSYS07.so_no
```

Comment: This gives me a "Didn't expect 'ISDATE' after the SELECT column list." error

Comment: You have an extra comma after the last item in the select list.  Try removing that

Comment: Thanks Adam Haines, I removed the extra comma